# Writing prometheus exporter supports multiple target in python

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus, exporter

I'm writing prometheus exporter scrapes multiple targets in Python. I've looked over Internet for example code but couldn't find. Anyone who have any ideas how to write this type of prometheus exporter. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like this could help: https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to scrape multiple similar endpoints? If so, you should probably configure Prometheus with multiple jobs, one for each of the endpoints that use the same exporter. If you have a complex exporter that itself combines multiple, related services, you may want to create multiple [Collectors](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#custom-collectors)

Comment: @DazWilkin Sorry for late reply. I'm writing a multi-target exporter like snmp exporter or blackbox exporter. I found a short description about this type of exporter: https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/multi-target-exporter . My exporter will login to multiple systems though SSH and then do some commands to get metrics. This exporter can not run on the machine the metrics are taken from.